# QMovie from QBuffer from QByteArray not displaying GIF

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, python-imaging-library, gif

I could use somebody's help to understand why `PyQt5.QtGui.QMovie` does not render but crash a GIF made from `PyQt5.QtCore.QBuffer` that is made out of `PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray`. I have branched out a [branch](https://github.com/AzisK/giffer/blob/qmovie-from-qbuffer-from-qbytearray/src/main/python/main.py#L215-L222) for this to be tried out in my application.

The simplified method `generate_gif` generating GIF from `PIL` library `Image` class looks like below. Other code is simply the whole simplified application.

Requirements: `Python3.6.9`

Libraries: `PyQt5==5.9.2`, `fbs`, `Pillow`

```py
import io
import sys
from typing import List

import requests
from PIL import Image
from PyQt5.QtCore import QByteArray, QBuffer, QIODevice, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QScrollArea, QWidget
from fbs_runtime.application_context.PyQt5 import ApplicationContext, cached_property

CORGI_URLS = [
    'https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/cute-pembroke-welsh-corgi-dog-cartoon-icon_42750-632.jpg',
    'https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/cute-welsh-corgi-puppy-lying-back-cartoon-icon_42750-352.jpg',
]
GIF_DELAY = 600


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, ctx):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ctx = ctx  # Store a reference to the context for resources, etc.
        self.title = "Giffer"
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)

        self.init_ui()
        self.showMaximized()

    def init_ui(self):
        vLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        vLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        scroll = QScrollArea()
        scroll.setWidgetResizable(1)
        widget = QWidget()
        scroll.setWidget(widget)

        widget.setLayout(vLayout)

        self.gif_view = self.setup_gif_view()
        vLayout.addWidget(self.gif_view)

        self.setCentralWidget(scroll)

    def setup_gif_view(self):
        label = QLabel()
        label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        return label

    def generate_gif(self):
        img: Image
        imgs: List[Image]
        img, *imgs = self.ctx.corgo_pics

        bytesio = io.BytesIO()
        img.save(fp=bytesio, format='GIF', append_images=imgs, save_all=True, duration=GIF_DELAY, loop=0)
        qbuffer = QBuffer(QByteArray(bytesio.getvalue()))

        gif = QMovie()
        gif.setDevice(qbuffer)

        self.gif_view.setMovie(gif)
        gif.start()


class AppContext(ApplicationContext):           # 1. Subclass ApplicationContext
    def run(self):                              # 2. Implement run()
        self.main_window.show()
        self.main_window.generate_gif()
        return self.app.exec_()                 # 3. End run() with this line

    @cached_property
    def main_window(self):
        return MainWindow(self)  # Pass context to the window.

    @cached_property
    def corgo_pics(self) -> List[Image]:
        imgs = []
        for url in CORGI_URLS:
            response = requests.get(url)
            imgs.append(Image.open(io.BytesIO(response.content)))
        return imgs


if __name__ == '__main__':
    appctxt = AppContext()                      # 4. Instantiate the subclass
    exit_code = appctxt.run()                   # 5. Invoke run()
    sys.exit(exit_code)
```

(right now in the application the method generating the GIF saves it to a file and then `QMovie` has no problems reading this file but I want to avoid saving to a file and reading from it)

---

### EDIT

After some reading and tweaking I changed it a bit by assigning `QByteArray(bytesio.getvalue())` to a value instead of directly passing it to `QBuffer`. I tried this because I read that QBuffer only takes the reference to this object. Therefore, if there is no reference to that object, I suppose Python's garbage collector destroys that `QByteArray`.
This seems to help because the program renders the first frame of the GIF but then it crashes. I suppose there is an additional memory problem. Is the `QBuffer` garbage collected after the executor exits the method?

I also added `gif.setCacheMode(QMovie.CacheAll)`.

Here is the simplified `generate_gif` method

```py
def generate_gif(self):
    img: Image
    imgs: List[Image]
    img, *imgs = self.ctx.corgo_pics

    bytesio = io.BytesIO()
    img.save(fp=bytesio, format='GIF', append_images=imgs, save_all=True, duration=GIF_DELAY, loop=0)
    qbytearray = QByteArray(bytesio.getvalue())
    bytesio.close()
    qbuffer = QBuffer(qbytearray)

    gif = QMovie()
    gif.setDevice(qbuffer)
    gif.setCacheMode(QMovie.CacheAll)
    print(f'Movie isValid() {gif.isValid()}')

    self.gif_view.setMovie(gif)
    gif.start()
```

On first run it crashes and I get such response:

```sh
Movie isValid() True
QIODevice::peek (QDesktopWidget, "desktop"): WriteOnly device
QIODevice::read (QDesktopWidget, "desktop"): WriteOnly device
QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
```

With consecutive runs it crashes and I see this:

```sh
Movie isValid() True

Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

Comment: Try adding `gif.resize.connect(self.gif_view.updateGeometry)` *before* `gif.start()`. Also, ensure that the movie [`isValid()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmovie.html#isValid).

Comment: Thanks @musicamante, now I am printing whether the `gif.isValid()`. It seems it is. I changed it a bit by assigning `QByteArray(bytesio.getvalue())` to a value instead of directly passing it to `QBuffer`. This seems to help because the program renders the first frame of the GIF but then it crashes

Comment: Please [edit] your post and provide a valid [mre]: questions shouldn't rely on external resources, especially if their content might change in the future (which is what happens with repositories) thus making the question invalid to others. Besides, `setMovie()` does *not* take ownership, so you should at least try to make it persistent or create it with the label as its parent.

Comment: I thought about this and for this reason I created a branch specifically for this issue and question but fair enough. I will provide a self sufficient minimal reproducible example for it.

I did not fully understand the part about `setMovie()`. `self.gif_view` is a `QLabel` (see in https://github.com/AzisK/giffer/blob/qmovie-from-qbuffer-from-qbytearray/src/main/python/main.py#L160-L163), is there something additional I should be aware of?

Comment: Yes, the docs about [`setMovie()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#setMovie) say that the label does *not* take ownership. But I believe that the problem here is that the QBuffer gets destroyed as soon as the function returns (and, strangely enough, even setting the label as its parent won't be enough). Try by adding `gif.jumpToFrame(gif.frameCount() - 1)` before starting, it should be enough to force QMovie to load (and cache) all the contents before returning.

Comment: I just added a minimal reproducible example and just tried out your suggestion. And it works! I am delighted to see this work. Thanks a bunch! I believe this is an elegant solution to cache the frames before returning but I would be curious how would you go about keeping the `QBuffer` alive and if that is even worth doing?

Comment: Please don't add an answer inside a question, use the `Answer your question` button instead.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that even parenting the QBuffer won't be enough to keep it alive avoiding garbage collection, so the program crashes because the buffer is destroyed while it's being accessed.

While you can obviously make it persistent by making it an attribute of the label (or a Qt dynamic property with `setProperty('gif', gif)`), using `setCacheMode(QMovie.CacheAll)` is enough to load the whole GIF and make it persistent, but the catch is that the gif has to be completely loaded before returning.

To achieve this, it should be enough to load the last frame:

```
    gif.jumpToFrame(gif.frameCount() - 1)
    gif.jumpToFrame(0)
    gif.start()
```

In case it won't be enough (but I don't see a reason for which it wouldn't), you can obviously load all frames:

```
    for f in range(gif.frameCount()):
        gif.jumpToFrame(f)
    gif.jumpToFrame(0)
    gif.start()
```

Note:

- you can directly add the buffer in the QMovie constructor, which will do the same as `gif.setDevice()`;
- `requests.get` is blocking, consider using a custom QThread with signals (but remember that the QMovie *must* be created in the main thread) or [QNetworkAccessManager](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html);

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been solved in the comments by the ingenious @musicamante. The solution is to add `gif.jumpToFrame(gif.frameCount() - 1)` before starting the `QMovie`. It forces `QMovie` to load (and cache) all the contents before returning. The problem with previous approach is that the `QBuffer` gets destroyed as soon as the function returns. Therefore, there is nothing to read the frames from (or that `QBuffer` reference may point to a completely different object in memory now).

Final simplified working `generate_gif` method:

```py
def generate_gif(self):
    img: Image
    imgs: List[Image]
    img, *imgs = self.ctx.corgo_pics

    bytesio = io.BytesIO()
    img.save(fp=bytesio, format='GIF', append_images=imgs, save_all=True, duration=GIF_DELAY, loop=0)
    qbytearray = QByteArray(bytesio.getvalue())
    bytesio.close()
    qbuffer = QBuffer(qbytearray)

    gif = QMovie()
    gif.setDevice(qbuffer)
    gif.setCacheMode(QMovie.CacheAll)
    print(f'Movie isValid() {gif.isValid()}')

    self.gif_view.setMovie(gif)
    gif.jumpToFrame(gif.frameCount() - 1)
    gif.start()
```

---

### EDIT

After playing a bit with the code I found another solution. The solution is to attach the `qbuffer` and the `qbytearray` to a global variable. `QMovie` only holds the reference to the object passed to it, it does not create a copy of the object and store it inside itself. `QBuffer` object gets destroyed after we return from `generate_gif` function because there is no variable referencing it anymore. Then `QMovie` tries to access the `QBuffer` object in memory which does not exist anymore. We can attach `QBuffer` to a global variable. Then it will not be garbage collected after the function returns. However, the problem still remains because the `QBuffer` points (it only has a reference to the object as well) to a `QByteArray` which gets destroyed after the function returns. We can solve this by attaching the `QByteArray` to a global variable. This way none of them will be garbage collected and then later they can be referenced. And it works! When I think about, it seems obvious. Nonetheless, I have never had to deal with a similar issue in Python until now. I must say that I also do not usually work with `pyqt`, bytes and pictures, so maybe this is the area where this knowledge will benefit me!

We also do not need to jump to the last frame anymore `gif.jumpToFrame(gif.frameCount() - 1)`

Final simplified working `generate_gif` method:

```py
def generate_gif(self):
    img: Image
    imgs: List[Image]
    img, *imgs = self.ctx.corgo_pics

    bytesio = io.BytesIO()
    img.save(fp=bytesio, format='GIF', append_images=imgs, save_all=True, duration=GIF_DELAY, loop=0)
    self.gif_qbytearray = QByteArray(bytesio.getvalue())

    bytesio.close()
    self.gif_qbuffer = QBuffer(self.gif_qbytearray)

    gif = QMovie()
    gif.setDevice(self.gif_qbuffer)
    gif.setCacheMode(QMovie.CacheAll)
    print(f'Movie isValid() {gif.isValid()}')

    self.gif_view.setMovie(gif)
    gif.start()
```

In my original application it is also beneficial to keep the `qbtearray` in a global variable because it has an option to save the GIF to a file. Thus, the bytearray should be available instead of having to regenerate it (as for an app that is here to help create GIFs, saving GIFs should be one the most fundamental functions).

---

### Final thoughts

If there is no need to later access the `qbytearray` in the app, I believe we would save some memory if we do not attach it to a global memory and let it be garbage collected because we have seen that the `QMovie` caches the image frames separately as well. We would then rely on `gif.jumpToFrame(gif.frameCount() - 1)` to cache the image frames and it would take some initial additional time to do so.

It is also possible to disable caching but have the `qbytearray` and `qbuffer` attached to a global variable. This way we would save some memory but the GIF image frames would have to be re-rendered every turn. This should take a little bit longer to render them. I believe it makes sense to cache a GIF since it is displaying the same frames over and over again.